# Cheap way to move stuff from USA to Western Europe

Tags: usa, france, eu, relocation, shipping

We (two people) are moving to France from the USA.  We can't carry all our stuff in suitcases, it's simply too much.  What is the cheapest safe way to move things?  Think the usual things one might want to bring, a few books, clothes, simple household items, and the odd weird thing one wouldn't part with (imagine anything from a small bicycle pump to LEGO pieces).

**Is USPS shipping the best way?**  If yes, what do I need to consider to make it go smoothly through customs?  I worry about things such as the package being opened at customs and many tiny things falling out.  Also, should I use my own box or get a box from USPS?  Can/should I get a wooden crate to make sure the box won't fall apart?

We would probably fit in about 25-40 kg (a very rough estimate).

As a clarification, this question has two main parts: (1) how to move cheaply (2) security, i.e. ensuring that everything arrives in good order.

Comment: Related: [Transporting a large number of books from USA to UK](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/1409/790)

Answer (score 2):

I will be using [USPS Priority Mail International](https://www.usps.com/international/priority-mail-international.htm).  This is the most affordable option I was able to find.