# Are ISAL M-bags (for shipping books abroad from USA) available for individuals?

Tags: usa, shipping, postal-system

I discovered with excitement [a post](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/transporting-a-large-number-of-books-from-usa-to-uk?rq=1) describing ISAL M-bags to ship a large amount of books abroad from the US. However when looking at the [USPS documentation](http://pe.usps.com/text/dmm300/Notice123.htm#2522322) indicated in the same post, ISAL M-bags figure in the "Commercial prices" rather than the "retail prices". So could someone confirm that ISAL M-bags are available for individuals?

The USPS offices I phoned in NYC did not know about these ISAL M-bags, or suggested it was for businesses and not available for individuals, and others said only airmail M-bag were available and ISAL M-bags were discontinued. If ISAL M-bags are indeed available for individuals, does anyone know of a USPS office in NYC which actually knows about this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**:

- In general USPS officers have no clues what ISAL M-bags are exactly, and will give different answers in each different branches (even branch managers)
- From what I could gather from the multiple different explanations, this service exists in theory, but is not available because of the latest update of the USPS software used in branches

Comment: I have tried today to get clarity on this and I get contradictory statements from each different postal employee I speak to. I've been told M-Bag doesn't even exist by one, which is clearly false. Postal employees simply have no knowledge of the product or how to do it so they make their best guesses.

Answer (score 2):

In my response below, seems I was wrong. USPS M-bags are for everyone (and available at a local USPS office). ISAL M-bags are for commercial use: http://pe.usps.com/text/imm/immc2_039.htm

> 293 International Surface Air Lift (ISAL) Service
>
> 293.1 Description
>
> 293.11 General
>
> International Surface Air Lift (ISAL) service, including ISAL M-bags,
>   is a commercial service designed for volume mailings of all
>   First-Class Mail International postcards, letters, and large envelopes
>   (flats), and for volume mailings of First-Class Package International
>   Service packages (small packets).

Why is it that you specifically want ISAL M-bags rather than USPS?

My old reply is below the line.

---

Yes, they are available for retail customers. I'll find a source and edit my response.

But anecdotally, I used an M-bag to mail my books to myself when I moved from Oregon to the UK 5 years ago. I have also found a few websites stating that M-bags are fine, you just need to verify that the bags are available at your local PO.

Comment: ISAL M-bags are from USPS, ISAL is just a mode of transportation. Compared to standard M-bags, ISAL M-bags are much cheaper. Also ISAL M-bags are actually available for everyone (not only for commercial use) in theory but in practice they are not available at all (cf my updated post)